# Video Poster play at delay

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to play my **'animation'** video at a delay. It needed to have a transparent background and no controller, so like a gif.

I figured video is the only solution, however now it's either running in a loop or running once.

Example image:

[image]

```
  <div id="nee">
  <video poster="" id="bgvid" playsinline muted>
    <source src="   rendermirror.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="rendermirror.mov" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Also tried using an interval, but i don't get it to work properly.

```
      var video = document.getElementById("bgvid");
  video.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      video.play();
    }, 5000);
  });
```

If anyone has any tips, would be really appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I `pause` the video when load and the video plays after `5s`

```js
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
// pause video event
video.pause();


video.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    video.play();
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

if you want to `loop` the video then you will need to add change this

```js
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
// pause video event
video.pause();


video.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    video.play();
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" loop>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```